# Delete HBase HDFS "splitlog" directory before restore?

Tags: hbase, hdfs

Is it safe to delete the "splitlog" directory in a HDFS backup (stored on Amazon S3) before restore?

It looks like our "splitlog" directory has gotten corrupt, and is preventing us from doing a full restore of our HBase cluster from the backup.